# snakemake: Use different folders for input and output files

Tags: snakemake

This is most likely a very basic issue, but I could not find it documented anywhere.

```
rule all:
    input:
        "fasta_file.fna"
    output:
        "headers.txt"
    shell:
        "grep "^>" {input} > {output}"
```

I want to run this for a set of files that are not necessarily in the same folder. Is there a way to provide as command (or config file) the input file name from another directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay never mind, this was probably no smart question indeed.

```
rule all:
    input:
        "input/{sample}.fna"
    output:
        "output/{sample}_headers.txt"
    shell:
        "grep "^>" {input} > {output}"
```

And with that I can just run snakemake for my target file, something like `snakemake output/A1_headers.txt`, or build a for loop over my input sequences.